How do you compile a C program to the same format that `nasm -f bin` produces?
I have looked around for some examples of simple C programs (that, by necessity, don't use the heap or standard library) and instructions on how to compile them so that they can be run under qemu, but so far I haven't found anything simple enough. (Ideally I want something small enough that I can tweak, rebuild, and run again, similar to the hello world bootloader example shown below.)
I am fine with a C program that contains substantial amounts of inline assembly.
I know almost nothing about bare metal development, bootloader development, or kernel development, and I'm trying to learn more by building random things and running them under qemu.
Ideally, I'd like to know how to write a program in a higher level language than assembly and get it to run under qemu.
I am working in a Debian-based a Linux container inside a Chromebook.
sh:1 $ uname -a
Linux penguin ############## #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 3 Oct 2024 12:57:30 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I grabbed a simple bootloader example from an article on Wikibooks (see Appendix A)
I then assembled it:
nasm -f bin -o floppy.img preamble.asm

The file utility recognized that this command produced a boot sector, which is good.
floppy.img: DOS/MBR boot sector

I can boot this image.
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -no-reboot floppy.img 

This opens up a graphical window and prints Hello World! with no newline over and over forever.
I'm wondering if there's a way to write a program for this environment in C rather than assembly.
Appendix A
         org 7C00h
 
         jmp short Start ;Jump over the data (the 'short' keyword makes the jmp instruction smaller)
 
 Msg:    db "Hello World! "
 EndMsg:
 
 Start:  mov bx, 000Fh   ;Page 0, colour attribute 15 (white) for the int 10 calls below
         mov cx, 1       ;We will want to write 1 character
         xor dx, dx      ;Start at top left corner
         mov ds, dx      ;Ensure ds = 0 (to let us load the message)
         cld             ;Ensure direction flag is cleared (for LODSB)
 
 Print:  mov si, Msg     ;Loads the address of the first byte of the message, 7C02h in this case
 
                         ;PC BIOS Interrupt 10 Subfunction 2 - Set cursor position
                         ;AH = 2
 Char:   mov ah, 2       ;BH = page, DH = row, DL = column
         int 10h
         lodsb           ;Load a byte of the message into AL.
                         ;Remember that DS is 0 and SI holds the
                         ;offset of one of the bytes of the message.
 
                         ;PC BIOS Interrupt 10 Subfunction 9 - Write character and colour
                         ;AH = 9
         mov ah, 9       ;BH = page, AL = character, BL = attribute, CX = character count
         int 10h
 
         inc dl          ;Advance cursor
 
         cmp dl, 80      ;Wrap around edge of screen if necessary
         jne Skip
         xor dl, dl
         inc dh
 
         cmp dh, 25      ;Wrap around bottom of screen if necessary
         jne Skip
         xor dh, dh
 
 Skip:   cmp si, EndMsg  ;If we're not at end of message,
         jne Char        ;continue loading characters
         jmp Print       ;otherwise restart from the beginning of the message
 
 
 times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$)  db 0    ;Zerofill up to 510 bytes
 
         dw 0AA55h       ;Boot Sector signature
 
 ;OPTIONAL:
 ;To zerofill up to the size of a standard 1.44MB, 3.5" floppy disk
 ;times 1474560 - ($ - $$) db 0


gcc -Xassembler -f -Xassembler bin ... should work (??): see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Assembler-Options.html

Maybe just compile the .c to .o files as normal, then write a custom linker script for ld?

The answer is yes, but it isn't easy or straight forward. You could use Open Watcom C/C++ to generate 8086/8088 code that runs as a bootloader in 16-bit real mode. There is a port of GCC for 16-bit 8086/8088 that is probably more ideal but it is a work in progress and using an older version of GCC as a base. It can be found here: https://github.com/tkchia/gcc-ia16 .

You can use a regular version of GCC using the -m16 option to generate code that runs in real mode but it is bloated and requires a 386+ CPU to run. I have an example project here: https://github.com/mpetch/OSDev/tree/master/examples/gcc-2stage-bootloader . It ises GCC inline assembly, a linker script and objcopy to convert an elf executable to binary. GCC can emit a binary directly but I prefer outputting as elf and using objcopy to aid in debugging.

My code example is a 2 stage bootloader. It is a 512 byte boot sector (stage 1) followed by a kernel (stage 2). Stagee 1 uses int 0x13 BIOS routines to read stage 2. The generated code using -m16 makes it a tight squeeze to write a bootloader this way. I don 't recommend this. It is easier to write a 16-bit bootloader in assembly and then switch into 32-bit protected mode to then run 32-bit code generated by GCC.
